# How to check setData() set the value or not

Tags: magento2, php

I have `$product->setData('phone_features', $avidee);` Now i want to check whether `phone_feature` value set or not.How can i check in magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $product object already you can check your value by using this code:

```
$product->getPhoneFeatures();
```

or

```
$product->getData('phone_features');
```

Answer (score 0):

In block :

```
public function getCatalogSession()
{
    return $this->catalogSession;
}
```

Then set attribute value in template :

```
$this->getCatalogSession()->setPhoneFeatures('hello');
$phoneFeature = $this->getCatalogSession()->getPhoneFeatures();

echo $phoneFeature; // hello
```